# Math Table in php?

Tags: php, refactoring

I want to get table value in php array.

```
 $values=array(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,19,20);
```

I tried something like this

```
<?php
 for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
 {
$values[]=2*$i;
 }

 ?>
```

Can i do better may be through some built in functions or some another technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that 19 is a typo:

```
$values = range(2, 20, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help i would look into documentation of range function thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$n=2; range($n, $n*10, $n);
```